# create-react-app does not pick up .env file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app, env-file

I created `.env` file in the root of my directory with data `REACT_APP_API_URL=http:\\localhost:3001`, but when I run and get value from `process.env`, I get an empty object, how can I fix that?

Comment: The `REACT_APP_API_URL` needs to be changed to `http://localhost:3001` with forward slashes I think. Although that may not be the solution to the entire problem, I believe you would run into that problem at some point or the other! Currently, the URL uses backslashes which do not form a valid URL.

Comment: I tries any types of strings, with and without slashes, no luck

Comment: Are you using Create react app or you have defined your own webpack configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate variable with start script.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3001 react-scripts start", //like this
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

then you need to run your app. it will take all paramerters.

Or another way to run it pass it using command line.
Ex: you need to pass env variable first before loading scripts

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3001  npm start
```

You can also use package for better env management([cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)) It will take care all env related management. Feel free to check there doc.

If you want to use cross-env you have to only do this for running enviornment from .env file(**Note**:.env file should be on package.json level)

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

it will load all your configuration from .env file whenever you want to use.